# getLastKnownLocation keeps returning null

Tags: android

I know several questions have been asked for this and I tried some of the answers but it doesn't work for me.

I have added permissions for both of location services but it persistently returns null.

Here is my [Java code](https://gist.github.com/mukundmadhav/42c9dfcab464a2fce56573a845957f5e).

Answer (score 0):

`provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(new Criteria(), false);`

You're providing `false` for the `enabledOnly` parameter, so it might be returning a provider that is not enabled. Then going by the javadocs for `getLastKnownLocation` it would return null: "If the provider is currently disabled, null is returned."

Comment: You are suggesting I should change enabledOnly value to true? I tried that. Does not work either.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of location manager you can use [FusedLocationApi](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi).

And code sample is here

```
   protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    //  Toast.makeText(getContext(), "buildGoogleApiClient", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
}

@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.


        return;
    }
    Location mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
            mGoogleApiClient);
    if (mLastLocation != null) {
        //place marker at current position
        // Log.e("x", mLastLocation.getLongitude() + "");
        //Log.e("y", mLastLocation.getLatitude() + "");
        currentLocation = mLastLocation;


    }

    LocationRequest mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(5000); //5 seconds
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(5000); //3 seconds
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
    mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(50F); //1/10 meter

    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    currentLocation = location;

}
```

Parameters that you need

```
 private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
 private Location currentLocation;
```

and call buildGoogleApiClient on activity or fragment onCreateMethode()